# In Jquery ajax.post is not firing without alert

Tags: jquery

I'm getting the values through ajax.post. The ajax.post returns some data in that data i need to bind the checkboxes. That i done with using alert message.. Its not firing without Alert.. Can u help

Answer (score 0):

What is the operation are you want to do? That means just you get the data's from ajax.post method and insert that data  to within the `div` or `table`.. that time you find this issue ?

Comment: yes, i'm getting values from success(data). In the data i'm going to check the checkbox depends upon values. Now i found an issue its not checked the checkbox without alert().. r u getting what i'm saying

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax is running asynchronously (which is the default, and a good idea) it is possible that the routine hasn't finished in time.

The alert causes your code to stop executing, giving enough time for the ajax to finish doing its thing and return a value.

You should test this hypothesis by setting your ajax to run synchronously (open a new browser window if you do this). Then take a look at the following article for help in setting up polling:

[Long Polling Example (using Jquery)](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

You can set your ajax to run synchronously by adding `async: false,` to the string of configurations for the method.

Note the syntax used in the long pollig example to better understand how to format your ajax routine. Don't leave it synchronous though! Doing so could cause the user's browser to lock up indefinitely if something goes wrong with the ajax method.